# Reading or exporting .yaml file in R

Tags: r, yaml

I have a huge data set for doing analysis in R which has `.yaml` extension and I want to export that data in R.

How can I do it ? Is there any package for doing that?
I want to do it on Windows platform.

Comment: have you tried [yaml package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=yaml) ?

Comment: could you please post the first few lines of your datafile?

Comment: sorry for late reply..

Comment: code snippet given below:---
meta:
  data_version: 0.7
  created: 2013-02-22
  revision: 1
info:
  city: Southampton
  dates:
    - 2005-06-13
  gender: male
  match_type: T20
  outcome:
    by:
      runs: 100
    winner: England
  overs: 20
  player_of_match:
    - KP Pietersen
  teams:
    - England
    - Australia
  toss:
    decision: bat
    winner: England
  umpires:
    - NJ Llong
    - JW Lloyds
  venue: The Rose Bowl